# Сделать функцию с текстом html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui

Есть код на *Python* с использованием библиотеки *PyQt5.*
В коде есть функция `dish_lib`, которая зависит от `QComboBox`, который называется `ComboViborBluda`.

Пользователь выбирает блюдо в комбобоксе и получает в `QLabel`, который называется `label_2` состав и КБЖУ этого блюда.

Все тексты описания (состав и КБЖУ) похожи между собой и я захотел укоротить код, тем самым сделать его чище, переведя весь `html` в отдельную функцию, вот только у меня не получается, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.

После слова "Состав:" и конца состава идет перенос строки (во втором случае двойной);
*В одной строке не должно быть больше 32 символов.*

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # настройки окна
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 546)
        self.ComboViborBluda.activated.connect(self.dish_lib)

    def dish_lib(self):
        if self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Гамбургер':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Булочка, Говяжья котлета,<br>Кетчуп, Горчица,<br>Лук, Огурцы '
                'маринованные<br>Приправа для гриля<br><br>КБЖУ - 257Ккал, 14г, 8,6г<br>29г.</p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Пицца':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Среднестатистическая <br>пицца:<br>Тесто, овощи, мясо,<br>Сыр, Соусы'
                '<br><br>Среднее КБЖУ - <br>340Ккал на кусок пиццы,<br>10г, 14г, 30г.</p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Салат "Цезарь"':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Листовый салат, <br>Сыр "Пармезан",<br>Сухарики пшеничные, '
                '<br>Соус "Цезарь"<br><br>КБЖУ - 375Ккал на порцию, 7,4г,<br>9г, 11г.</p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Салат "Греческий"':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Помидоры, Перец болг.<br>Огурцы, Лук, Брынза,<br>Маслины, Соус<br>'
                '<br>КБЖУ - 877Ккал на порцию,<br>25г, 64г, 41г. </p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Картошка Фри':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Картошка.<br><br>КБЖУ - 274Ккал, 3,48г,<br>35,66г, 14,06г</p></body>'
                '</head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Картошка по-деревенски (Айдахо)':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Картошка<br><br>КБЖУ - 331Ккал, 4.6г, <br>15г, 42г.</p></body></head>'
                '</html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Наггетсы':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Котлеты куриные<br><br>КБЖУ - 440Ккал, 25г,<br>21г, 28г.</p></body>'
                '</head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Крылышки':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Куриные крылья, Специи<br><br>КБЖУ - 487Ккал на одно крыло,<br>28,4г,'
                ' 31,5г, 22,5г.</p></body></head></html>')
        else:
            self.label_2.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design_project.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 546)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ComboViborBluda = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboViborBluda.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 310, 211, 22))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setObjectName("ComboViborBluda")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 370, 171, 131))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

            def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "*Блюдо не выбрано*"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Гамбургер"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Пицца"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Цезарь\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Греческий\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка Фри"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка по-деревенски (Айдахо)"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "Наггетсы"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "Крылышки"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще не понимаю зачем вам `html`? Ведь в дальнейшем это все будет в базе данных,
если  вас правильно понял.

Я вам предложу попробовать поменять `QLabel` на `QTextEdit`, пока вы не освоите БД.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


#from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 546)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ComboViborBluda = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboViborBluda.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 310, 211, 22))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setObjectName("ComboViborBluda")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.ComboViborBluda.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 370, 171, 131))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "*Блюдо не выбрано*"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Гамбургер"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Пицца"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Цезарь\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Салат \"Греческий\""))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка Фри"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "Картошка по-деревенски (Айдахо)"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "Наггетсы"))
        self.ComboViborBluda.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "Крылышки"))


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # настройки окна
        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 546)
        self.ComboViborBluda.activated.connect(self.dish_lib)
        
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 370, 171, 131))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ccc;")
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)

    def dish_lib(self):
        if self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Гамбургер':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Булочка, Говяжья котлета,<br>Кетчуп, Горчица,<br>Лук, Огурцы '
                'маринованные<br>Приправа для гриля<br><br>КБЖУ - 257Ккал, 14г, 8,6г<br>29г.</p></body></head></html>')

# +++
            self.textEdit.setPlainText("""
Состав:
Булочка, Говяжья котлета, Кетчуп, Горчица, Лук, Огурцы маринованные, \
Приправа для гриля

КБЖУ - 257Ккал, 14г, 8,6г, 29г.
""")
# +++

        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Пицца':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Среднестатистическая <br>пицца:<br>Тесто, овощи, мясо,<br>Сыр, Соусы'
                '<br><br>Среднее КБЖУ - <br>340Ккал на кусок пиццы,<br>10г, 14г, 30г.</p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Салат "Цезарь"':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Листовый салат, <br>Сыр "Пармезан",<br>Сухарики пшеничные, '
                '<br>Соус "Цезарь"<br><br>КБЖУ - 375Ккал на порцию, 7,4г,<br>9г, 11г.</p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Салат "Греческий"':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Помидоры, Перец болг.<br>Огурцы, Лук, Брынза,<br>Маслины, Соус<br>'
                '<br>КБЖУ - 877Ккал на порцию,<br>25г, 64г, 41г. </p></body></head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Картошка Фри':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Картошка.<br><br>КБЖУ - 274Ккал, 3,48г,<br>35,66г, 14,06г</p></body>'
                '</head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Картошка по-деревенски (Айдахо)':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Картошка<br><br>КБЖУ - 331Ккал, 4.6г, <br>15г, 42г.</p></body></head>'
                '</html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Наггетсы':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Котлеты куриные<br><br>КБЖУ - 440Ккал, 25г,<br>21г, 28г.</p></body>'
                '</head></html>')
        elif self.ComboViborBluda.currentText() == 'Крылышки':
            self.label_2.setText(
                '<html><head><body><p>Состав:<br>Куриные крылья, Специи<br><br>КБЖУ - 487Ккал на одно крыло,<br>28,4г,'
                ' 31,5г, 22,5г.</p></body></head></html>')
        else:
            self.label_2.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужна функция, в которой будет шаблон текста. Чтобы вместо такого большого количества строк использовать функцию

Comment: @Diazz никакая функция/метод не сделает ваш код короче. Вам нужны форма в виде диалогового окна, в которой вы будете вводить данные и сохранять в БД.